# Android unable to successfully convert HTTP image/jpeg response to Bitmap

Tags: android, image, http, encoding, character-encoding

I am sending images from a server script using image/jpeg type response. Here is the server code (php using CodeIgniter):

```
       $file = file_get_contents("http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-5.jpg");
       $this->output->set_header("Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8");
       $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
       $this->output->set_header("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
       $this->output->set_header("Accept-Encoding", "");
       $this->output->set_output($file);
```

And this script sends the image to android, where I try to decode using the following script:

```
Log.e("response",response);
            try {
                String decompressedResponse = decompress(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));       
                InputStream instream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decompressedResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                Log.e("inputstream",instream.toString());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int len = 0;
                try {
                    while ((len = instream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    baos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                Log.e("bytearray",b.toString());
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e("UnsupportedEcondingEception","UNSUPPORTEDENCODINGEXCEPTIOn");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                return;
            }
```

Logcatting the response shows characters like this:

```
���8�@
```

**The really weird thing here is that if I call this script from a web browser, it displays the image but apparently android and eclipse cannot decode this encoding.**

I think it is an android problem rather than the server's. Any suggestions, hints are really appreciated as I have been stuck for a while.

Comment: For an image one does not set a charset. A charset is for text. So remove all of the utf-8 stuff in php. Moreover you try to read the input stream twice. The first time into a string. Remove completely all with decompressed and utf-8.

Comment: You are not showing how you got 'response'. You do not need variable response either. Just open an inputstream. Read from it in a loop and directly  write to a byte array or boas if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This might be the problem but I just used Picasso image loading library instead and let it do the work.